# Clear data when refresh the JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page that accepts data to be added in the database but whenever i refresh the page it process again the data and the problem is that when i refresh the page the data input will be saved again in the database. How can i clear the current data that is being sent to the servlet? when i refresh the page this pops out

"The page you're looking for used information that you entered. Returning to that page might cause any action you took to be repeated. Do you want to continue?".

Comment: Look into `POST-REDIRECT-GET`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis is one servlet enough for the whole web project?or it is ok to have several servlets?

Comment: A popular pattern for web applications is the Front Controller where you have one entry point (one `Servlet`) that handles everything. It's ok to have many servlets.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis could you tell me if i understand the POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern. based on what i've read. when the form submited to a servlet it process it and save to database and pass it to another servlet using GET(eg. servlet?value=true) and in the 2nd servlet it only shows or redirect to the new page.am i correct?

Comment: You start off submitting a form. This is typically a POST request sent with url encoded form parameters. The server receives the request and generates an HTTP response with a 302 response code and `Location` header pointing to another URL. The client then does another GET request on that URL. The server responds with an empty form (or whatever else).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis would that take a long time to load? sending the data POST server redirect then do Get. I just want to prevent my jsp page to reprocess the data inputs when i refresh the page.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis what is happening is that i want the request scope to be available once. after submitting the form i put value in request attribute then display it to the page, then when i refresh the page i want the request scope to be gone/deleted/dont exist?

Comment: Request scope is already gone. What happens is that your browser repeats the same request it previously did, containing all the same form inputs. This is a client problem, not a server problem.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can i do something like this i submit data through POST and in servlet i save to data base and response.sendRedirect("jsppage/data=tobedisplayed"); is it a good implementation?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis how am i able to access the request scope if i will use a GET method?

Answer (score 1):

2 ways to do that:

onclient site: use action onclick on save button and clear value

```
function reset(){
document.getElementById('yourtextbox').value="";
}
```

on server: after save action success, you set textbox value:

```
request.setAttribute("yourtextbox") = "";
```

it's longtime I have not work on jsp,so the method setAttribute I do not remember correctly